# Transformar diccionario de dataframes en un solo DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Tengo un diccionario que tiene dataframes de Pandas como valores. Quiero obtener un nuevo `DataFrame` uniendo todos los dataframes contenidos en el diccionario. El problema es que necesito crear una nueva columna en la que cada fila tiene el valor de la clave de ese `DataFrame` en el diccionario.

Creo que se entenderá mejor con un ejemplo:

Tenemos el siguiente diccionario, al que llamaremos `diccionario`:

```
{0:     count  eclipse_id
    7      19       10453
    56     12       11305
    48     11       11305

 1:     count  eclipse_id
    13      9       11305
    9       5       11339}
```

El objetivo es transformarlo en:

```
count   item_id    user_id
   19     10453          0
   12     11305          0
   11     11305          0
    9     11305          1
    5     11339          1
```

Como se puede observar, el valor de cada fila de la columna `user_id` se corresponde con la clave que su respectivo DataFrame tenía en el diccionario original.

Comment: el 'diccionario' tal y como está no es un diccionario Python válido. Tienes dos claves (0 y 1) pero no hay diccinario anidado. ¿Es en realidad un diccionario en donde **el valor es un `DataFrame`** (y no un diccionario )  y la **clave se corresponde al `user_id`**?

Comment: @FJSevilla Si !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo más simple es valerte de [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) y usar su parámetro `keys` para crear la nueva columna. Al parámetro `keys` se le pasa un iterable con un item por cada dataframe a concatenar y este item es usado para crear un nuevo índice. Solo te queda pasar ese índice a una columna normal y renombrarlo a "user_id":

```
import pandas as pd


#Creamos un diccionario de DataFrames para emular tu ejemplo
datos = {0: pd.DataFrame({'count': [19, 12, 21],
                          'eclipse_id': [10453, 11305, 11305]},
                          index = [7, 56, 48]),
         1: pd.DataFrame({'count': [9, 5],
                          'eclipse_id': [11305, 11339]},
                          index = [13, 9])
         }


# Ahora el diccionario "datos" es igual al que tu presentas.

df = pd.concat(datos.values(), keys=datos.keys())
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace =True)
df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'user_id'}, inplace=True)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> >>> df    
>
>     user_id  count  eclipse_id
> 7         0     19       10453
> 56        0     12       11305
> 48        0     21       11305
> 13        1      9       11305
> 9         1      5       11339
> ```

Puedes cambiar el orden de las columnas, ordenarlo como quieras o cambiar el índice.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Y como deshacerse con la primera columna ?

Comment: @Marine1 la primera columna es el índice, todo DataFrame necesita un índice. Puedes reindexar para que el índice sea  0,1,2,3.... o tienes que usar alguna de las otras columnas como índice. En el primer caso simplemente debes hacer `df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)`.

Comment: Y podria haberlo de [esta manera](https://image.ibb.co/mqnhsv/data_Frame_Without_Index.png) ?
Es para utilizarlo con `ranking_factorization_recommender.create`

Comment: Ha, creo que he entendido : Este último es un SFrame !